# Laravel-Snappy PDF Suddenly stopped working - Windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-snappy

I am using Snappy PDF(Windows 10 Local Development)

```
wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)
```

`config\snappy.php` file looks like this

```
<?php

return array(


    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe"',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),

 );
```

It suddenly stopped working

```
The exit status code '-1073740771' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [========> ] 14% [=================> ] 29% [=====================> ] 36% [========================> ] 41% QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files [==========================> ] 44% [===========================> ] 46% [=============================> ] 49% [============================================================] 100% " stdout: "" command: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --lowquality --orientation "landscape" --page-size "a5" --footer-right "Page [page] of [topage]"
```

This issue is only in the windows environment. I checked my production which is on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned the port 8080 to a Physical printer.
Corrected it and everything works fine now.